# Decimal ToString() conversion issue in C#

Tags: c#, string, decimal

I am facing a problem when I try to convert `decimal?` to `string`. Scenario is

```
decimal decimalValue = .1211;
string value = (decimalValue * 100).ToString();
```

Current Result : value = 12.1100

Expected Result : value = 12.11

Please let me know, what could be reason for this.

Comment: The reason is probably the system's default numeric format for decimal numbers.

Comment: Did you want it to display more than two decimal places if they're non-zero? That is, if you had `.12113405` you would want it to appear as `12.113405`?

Comment: Just what I was thinking: is it just the trailing zeroes, or do you want to always limit by 2 decimals? In the former case, none of the answers provide a good answer.

Comment: Want to know the reason, why toString() method is adding two extra zero.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Decimal` preserves any trailing zeroes in a `Decimal` number. If you want two decimal places instead:

```
decimal? decimalValue = .1211m;
string value = ((decimal)(decimalValue * 100)).ToString("#.##")
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

or

```
string value = ((decimal)(decimalValue * 100)).ToString("N2")
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

From [`System.Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx):

> A decimal number is a floating-point
>   value that consists of a sign, a
>   numeric value where each digit in the
>   value ranges from 0 to 9, and ***a
>   scaling factor that indicates the
>   position of a floating decimal point
>   that separates the integral and
>   fractional parts of the numeric value.***
>
> The binary representation of a Decimal
>   value consists of a 1-bit sign, a
>   96-bit integer number, and a scaling
>   factor used to divide the 96-bit
>   integer and specify what portion of it
>   is a decimal fraction. The scaling
>   factor is implicitly the number 10,
>   raised to an exponent ranging from 0
>   to 28. Therefore, the binary
>   representation of a Decimal value is
>   of the form, ((-2<sup>96</sup> to 2<sup>96</sup>) / 10<sup>(0 to
>   28)</sup>), where -2<sup>96</sup>-1 is equal to
>   MinValue, and 2<sup>96</sup>-1 is equal to
>   MaxValue.
>
> ***The scaling factor also preserves any
>   trailing zeroes in a Decimal number.
>   Trailing zeroes do not affect the
>   value of a Decimal number in
>   arithmetic or comparison operations.
>   However, >>trailing zeroes can be
>   revealed by the ToString method if an
>   appropriate format string is applied<<.***

Remarks:

1. the decimal multiplication needs to be casted to decimal, because `Nullable<decimal>.ToString` has no format provider
2. as Chris pointed out you need to handle the case that the `Nullable<decimal>` is `null`. One way is using the `Null-Coalescing-Operator`:

   ```
   ((decimal)(decimalValue ?? 0 * 100)).ToString("N2")
   ```

This article from Jon Skeet is worth reading:

[Decimal floating point in .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) (seach for *keeping zeroes* if you're impatient)

Comment: Casting to `decimal` will throw an `InvalidOperationException` with this code, whereas Pushkar's original code would result in an empty string. Possibly not relevant in this case though.

Comment: Sorry Tim, I meant it will throw when `decimalValue` is `null`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I know, it can be solved by specifying the formatter but I want to know why toString() method is adding extra zero.

Comment: @Pushkar: Have you read my quoted msdn link? _"The scaling factor also preserves any trailing zeroes in a Decimal number....trailing zeroes can be revealed by the ToString method if an appropriate format string is applied"_ Your original decimal has 4 dcimal places, hence `ToString` reveals them.  Btw, here's an explanation why it can be useful to remember the number of trailing zeros: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2996821/284240

Answer (score 6):

Since you using `Nullable<T>` as your `decimal`, [`Nullable<T>.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method doesn't have overloading takes parameters that you can use for formatting.

Instead of, you can explicitly cast it to `decimal` and you can use `.ToString()` method for formatting.

Just use `"0.00"` format in your `.ToString()` method.

```
decimal? decimalValue = .1211M;
string value = ((decimal)(decimalValue * 100)).ToString("0.00");
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Output will be;

```
12.11
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/zRPIhf).

As an alternative, you can use [`Nullable<T>.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx) without any conversation like;

```
string value = (decimalValue * 100).Value.ToString("0.00");
```

Check out for more information from [`Custom Numeric Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Comment: Casting to `decimal` will throw an `InvalidOperationException` with this code, whereas Pushkar's original code would result in an empty string. Possibly not relevant in this case though.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair No, it will not throw any exception in this case.

Comment: It does when I run the code verbatim in LinqPad. EDIT: Shoot sorry, I meant for when `decimalValue` is `null`. Sorry, I forgot to actually _write_ that.

Comment: Sorry Soner, I forgot to write that that's for the `null` case when `decimalValue` is null.

Comment: There is no need for cast and additional brackets, `Nullable<T>` has property `Value` that would return `T` or in this case `decimal`.

Comment: @EmperorOrionii Yeah, of course. That's another option also `;)`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can specify the format "F2", like so: `string val = decVal.ToString("F2")` as this specifies 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [fixed-point ("F) format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#FFormatString) .

```
   string value = (decimalValue * 100).ToString("F");
```

The default precision specifier is based on value of **NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits** property which by default has value 2. So if don't specify a digit aftyer "F" , it by default specifies two decimal digits.

```
F0 - No decimal places
F1 - One decimal place
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not want to limit to a certain amount of decimal digits:

```
decimal? decimalValue = .1211;
string value = decimalValue == null 
               ? "0"
               : decimalValue == 0
               ? "0"
               : (decimalValue * 100).ToString().TrimEnd('0');
```

This will trim any (if any) trailing zeroes of the string and also return "0" if `decimalValue` is null. If the value is 0 then "0" is returned without trimming.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", decimalValue * 100);
```

You can use `.Format()` as an alternative to `.ToString("0.00"`).

Answer (score 0):

Since `decimal?` does not have a `ToString(string format)` overload, the easiest way is to use `String.Format` instead which will provide consistent results with the `null` case for `decimalValue` as well (resulting in an empty string) when compared to your original code:

```
string value = String.Format("{0:#.##}", decimalValue * 100);
```

But there are some other considerations for other numbers that you weren't clear on.

If you have a number that does not produce a value greater than 0, does it show a leading zero? That is, for `0.001211`, does it display as `0.12` or `.12`? If you want the leading zero, use this instead (notice the change from `#.##` to `0.##`):

```
string value = String.Format("{0:0.##}", decimalValue * 100);
```

If you have more than 2 significant decimal places, do you want those displayed? So if you had `.12113405` would it display as `12.113405`? If so use:

```
string value = String.Format("{0:#.############}", decimalValue * 100);
```

(honestly, I think there must be a *better* formatting string than that, especially as it only supports 12 decimal places)

And of course if you want both leading zeros *and* multiple decimal places, just combine the two above:

```
string value = String.Format("{0:0.############}", decimalValue * 100);
```