# Incosistent conversion from object to string

Tags: c#, reflection, type-conversion

I have a decimal? property called Balance in a class. I have two objects of this class and value for Balance in both object is same (let's say 100).
I use reflection to get value of Balance from both objects like this

```
object bal1= type.GetProperty("Balance").GetValue(object1);
object bal2= type.GetProperty("Balance").GetValue(object2);
```

When I convert the object to string then I get different values.

```
Console.WriteLine(bal1.ToString()); // output : 100.00
Console.WriteLine(bal2.ToString()); // output : 100
```

Can someone explain what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

> Balance in both object is same

No, it isn't. A decimal remembers how many significant digits it got assigned. This code:

```
decimal d1 = 100m;
decimal d2 = 100.000m;

Console.WriteLine(d1);
Console.WriteLine(d2);
```

Will print:

```
100
100.000
```

See also [Why does a C# System.Decimal remember trailing zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996775/why-does-a-c-sharp-system-decimal-remember-trailing-zeros).