# Decimal ToString returns different values in different PCs

Tags: c#

I am facing a problem there is my code:

```
decimal i = 5;
return i.ToString();
```

above code in my PC returns 5.0 but in another PC returns 5
I know I can fix it by custom numeric format string [there is answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)
but I have no idea what is the cause of the problem?

can anyone tell me please

Comment: Why do you want to fix it? `ToString` is supposed to transform the number to a text output appropriate to the user currently using the computer (e.g. using local culture settings etc.). Do you want to override the user's preferences for some reason?

Comment: To get the same result every time, format with `.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

Comment: Are you sure this is the real code? For `decimal`, it's expected that the number of decimal digits is saved and respected by `ToString()`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996775/why-does-a-c-sharp-system-decimal-remember-trailing-zeros

Comment: No I wanna know what's the reason of this problem @Luaan

Comment: The Decimal type is very unusual, it can remember the number of significant digits used to specify the value.  The other floating point types (float and double) can't do that at all.  Matters in source code, also plays a role when the value is retrieved from a dbase table, now the default format depends on how the data was entered.  While that is very much a feature, it is not often desirable.  So do use the specific format you want to avoid surprises.

Comment: Are you running exactly this code on multiple PCs? Or you are getting that decimal value (5) from elsewhere, like database, file?

Comment: @SadeghAlinejad: It's only a problem if something's not working the way it should. If you're only curious to understadn the behavior (without needing to change it), then it's a question. This seems pedantic; but Luaan's comment is written precisely because they infer you want to _change_ the behavior because you've labeled it a "problem".

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that exhibits the problem. The reason for my request is that I want to see the exact code that is producing the problem. Right now it seems the bug is on *your* computer because the code in the question (right now) isn't supposed to return "5.0" or "5,0", it's supposed to return "5" because the Decimal type knows how many fractional digits it should contain, which in this case is none. As @Evk asked, did you get the 5 from a different source? Perhaps the problem/difference is there? In any case, post a [mcve].